# NSFileHandler returns nil for assets library video url

Tags: ios, objective-c, assets, alassetslibrary, filehandle

This is how my assests-library video URL is, **assets-library://asset/asset.mov?id=6EDBB011-3C29-4502-A688-5467E420376A&ext=mov**.

But when I pass this URL to NSFileHandler, it returns nil with error.

```
 NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingFromURL:mediaURL error:&error];
```

Error is,

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 2.)" UserInfo=0x15dbc0c0
>   {NSFilePath=/asset.mov}.

How to solve the issue?

Comment: Show how are you getting the url?

Comment: You can't load alasset library assets in that way. You need to use ALAssetLibrary class and it's methods for loading the images.

Answer (score 0):

The URL is valid only while the AlassetsLibrary is allocated. Check your ALAssetsLibrary is still not nil while you attempt to access the url with file handle.

**Added**

In this kind of case, you can use `singleton` pattern.

.h

```
@interface AssetsHelper : ALAssetsLibrary
+ (ALAssetsLibrary *)shared;
@end
```

.m

```
@implementation AssetsHelper
+ (ALAssetsLibrary *)shared {
    static ALAssetsLibrary *library = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken = 0;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    });
    return library;
}
@end
```

Then, you can get the same `ALAssetsLibrary` instance wherever you call `[ALAssetsHelper shared]`.

Comment: That URL Im sending from another class .

Comment: Using same URL Im opening that video in Instagram app. If URL is invalid how does it open in Instagram app?

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue by saving assets-Library video to temporary location and using that location path to NSFileHandle. I guess its not possible to send assert URl path to NSFileHandle.

Comment: Bad solution, as it duplicates files unnecessarily. As Midhun MP said, you have to use the `ALAssetLibrary` to interact with assets in the library.